# Link to Open in Same Window

Tags: dynamic, hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sites

Is there any way, using Google Apps Script, to create a link (with arguments) that will open in the same window on a Google Sites page?

I have explored an embedded gadget using UiApp (createAnchor), an embedded gadget using HtmlService, and an embedded gadget where the links were constructed to point at the web-app URL of the application rather than the parent page of the embedded gadget.

Either the link opens in a new window (UiApp, and HtmlService when I included "target=_blank" in the link), or it loads in the iframe of the gadget (HtmlService), or it strips the arguments from the link address (web-app URL).

I'm at a loss. How do people go about creating dynamic content that contains links (for instance: menus) for google sites?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do that with Google Apps Script due to Caja limitations (again....).
To learn more about that you can have a look at the documentation on [caja and anchors](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#anchor_tags)

Comment: Thanks for the info, @Harold... I spent a lot of time beating my head against a wall for no reason, apparently, but at least I know now it's impossible... At least there doesn't have to be any *more* beating m head against the wall.